# In MVC3 I am trying to get my dropdownlistfor to have a Value of zero , instead of empty string for the starting "Please Select ..."

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

How can I get the first Option Value to be zero instead of an empty string. So when the user
goest to the form and doesnt select anything a Value would be passed like zero. I am new to MVC and have spent time trying to find an easy answer. Can this be done in Jquery? Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

HERES my VIEW

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ItemCatId,
 new SelectList(Model.CategoryddList, "Value", "Text"),
 "Select Category")
```

AND CONTROLLER

```
items.CategoryddList =
        itemsRepository.GetItemDdl("Item Categories").Select(c => new SelectListItem 
                        {
                           Value = c.DropdownID.ToString(),
                           Text = c.DropdownText
                        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like many problems, There are many ways to do it. Jquery and Javascript are an option. The quickest (and lazy) way for me is to add an extra item at the top of the list with the value "please select". I don't know how your facade works but it should be something like this

```
items.CategoryddList = new Category( null , 0, “Please Select …”); //add the default
//rest of your code
items.CategoryddList =
    itemsRepository.GetItemDdl("Item Categories").Select(c => new SelectListItem 
                    {
                       Value = c.DropdownID.ToString(),
                       Text = c.DropdownText
                    });
```

Remember, you would have to handle that case in your HTTPPost action as well.

Another way is to not use the razor @Html.DropDownListFor and using an HTML with a foreach inside it.
 I will try looking up other methods to do this later

Edit: here is another way to do it from the view (I can't find a quick Jquery code right now). Try this:

```
<select name="FOOName"  id="FOOName" onchange="test(this)">
   <option value=""> Please Select</option>
   @{ foreach (var type in Model.CategoryddList)
   { 
    <option value="@type.Value"> @type.Text </option>
   }
}
</select>
```

Comment: My backend is little complicated to add to the list.(or I just to green to figure it out). Could you provide me a jquery way. I tried it but wasnt working for me.  $('.ItemTypeId').val("0");

Comment: try now? I am not that great with Jquery.

Comment: Thanks Ammar.  That Foreach I understand, Ill do that. Thanks again for you time.